# how to execute the hg clone command from windows

Tags: google-code

I have to download some source code from google code. But unfortunately the source code is available within the `hg clone` command:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/fr-belote/
```

How I download this source code from windows. The `hg clone` command is very new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install "Tortoise Hg Workbench" and then from command line you can execute commands like "hg clone https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/"